# Any alternate for _.invert() of underscore in javascript/jQUERY which can allow duplicate keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I need to change the existing map swapping keys into values and values into keys. As there is duplicate values in my map for the keys I cannot use `_.invert()` of `underscore library`.

```
     function map() {
        return {
             'eatables': {
                 apple: 'fruits',
                 orange: 'fruits',
                 guava: 'fruits',
                 brinjal: 'vegetables',
                 beans: 'vegetables',
                 rose: 'flowers',
             }
        }
    }

    var reverseMap = _.invert(map()['eatables']); 
// invert function works for distinct values.
    console.log (reverseMap); 
// which is giving Object {fruits: "guava", vegetables: "brinjal",flowers:"rose"}
```

But i am expecting an output as

```
Object {fruits: ["apple","orange","guava"], vegetables: ["brinjal","beans"], flowers:"rose"}
```

Any one liner is good to prefer for this, in any of the libraries or an easy way of doing it in jQuery/javascript.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: That's quite confusing to name a function `array()` which doesn't return an array...

Comment: Editing a question which has been answered as to alter the question to invalidate the answers is not a very good approach to getting help. In the future accept an answer for the ORIGINAL question if it has been answered and either ask the author of the answer any followup questions or post a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a solution without using 3rd party libraries you could use `Object.keys()` to generate an array of keys from the original object to then use `Array.prototype.reduce` to iterate over to create the desired object.

```
function invert(srcObj) {
  return Object.keys(srcObj).reduce(function(obj, val) {
    var key = srcObj[val];

    if (!obj[key]) { obj[key] = []; }

    obj[key].push(val);

    return obj;
  }, {});
}
```

```js
var origObj = {
    'eatables': {
      apple: 'fruits',
      orange: 'fruits',
      guava: 'fruits',
      brinjal: 'vegetables',
      beans: 'vegetables',
    }
  };

var newObj = invert(origObj.eatables);
    
function invert(srcObj) {
  return Object.keys(srcObj).reduce(function(obj, val) {
    var key = srcObj[val];

    if (!obj[key]) { obj[key] = []; }

    obj[key].push(val);

    return obj;
  }, {});
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newObj, null, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason, In your code while swapping key to values you are converting all the keys into an array, which holds good if keys has multiple values. I guess for cases if one value is mapped with one key it should be great if it as string rather than array.

Comment: @NaveenkumarChinnakalappa That's an easy update but not what your original question asked (or even had in the example). I would say that should be an easy change for you to make.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following snippet:

```
var reverseMap = {};
$.each(map().eatables, function(k, v){
    if(!reverseMap[v]) reverseMap[v] = [];
    reverseMap[v].push(k);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is a `map` or `forEach`, and manually reverse the keys and values to push them into an object . *(I recommend a forEach because the mapping function will return a mapped value and in this case is not what you are going to do and could be confusing)*

```
var reverseEatables = {};

_.forEach(array()['eatables'], function(value, key){
  if(!Array.isArray(eatables[value])){
    reverseEatables[value] = []; // verify the attribute in the object exist
  }
    reverseEatables[value].push(key);  
})
```